# String List doesn't work with Spinner ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, types, spinner

I'm building a `spinner` inside my `activity` and due to type `Adapter` requirements, I've to cast a `List<String>` to a `String[]` of variable length.

this is **my code** to retrieve objects from server (using `volley`):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.course_choice_activity);

    cChoice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);
    fChoices = new ArrayList<>();
    c = new Course();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    cl = new ArrayList<>();
    sm = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    rm = new RequestManager(CourseChoice.this);


    rm.getAllCourses(new VolleyCallbackOp() {
        public void onSuccess4(List<Course> cl) {
            String[] choices = new String[cl.size()];
            for (int a = 0; a < cl.size(); a++) {
                Course c = cl.get(a);
                choices[a] = c.toString();
            }
        }
    });


    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices) {
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            if (position % 2 == 1) {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC9A3FF"));
            } else {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAF89E5"));
            }
            return view;
        }
    };
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
    cChoice.setAdapter(aa);
    cChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String choice = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            if (choice != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected : " + choice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error has occurered..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

The Course `toString()` method return a string with its name.
Inside for loop it's all right, `fChoices` is populated with all course names. Once outside, `fChoice` turn to `null` value and then choices too.

The adapter I've to use is the following:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices) {...}
```

I tried to pass `fChoices` to adapter too (switching it from String to Course type but it didn't work. 
Anyone has an hint?

Error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...activities.CourseChoice}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
 at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3826)
 at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3813)
 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:139)
 at ....activities.CourseChoice$2.<init>(CourseChoice.java:99)
 at ....activities.CourseChoice.onCreate(CourseChoice.java:99)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Comment: where you set spinner adapter ?

Comment: immediately after the previous retrieving loop..

Comment: please share your whole code.

Comment: you wrote this `String[] choices = new String[cl.size()];` choices will be accessible only in  `onSuccess4` method of volley. so how you set `choices` in adapter that will make errro.

Comment: if i declare "String[] choices"; and then initialize it in onSuccess4 could solve the problem..but it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**: define the fake course and choice data, just for testing.probably will work.
the reason of your NullPointerException is that the request is executing in a different thread other than the current thread "main" .so a null value is passed to the adapter before the request is finished and your data is fetched.

---

Try to move adapter initialization just after the callback had finished.to make sure it's initialized in the same thread and the data is retrieved successfully.

**Note :** it's important to check if your data is retrieved successfully or not, that there are neither network error happened nor request timeout reached.so don't forget to check if data is not Null. you would show error message to the user.

```
rm.getAllCourses(new VolleyCallbackOp() {
        public void onSuccess4(List<Course> cl) {
            String[] choices = new String[cl.size()];
            for (int a = 0; a < cl.size(); a++) {
                Course c = cl.get(a);
                choices[a] = c.toString();
            }

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices) {
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            if (position % 2 == 1) {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC9A3FF"));
            } else {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAF89E5"));
            }
            return view;
        }
    };
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
    cChoice.setAdapter(aa);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yeah this is the same i've tought..i try this work-around cause i cannot put all inside the volleycallback:

rm.getAllCourses(new VolleyCallbackOp() {
            public void onSuccess4(List<Course> cl) {
                choices = new String[cl.size()];
                for (int a = 0; a < cl.size(); a++) {
                    Course c = cl.get(a);
                    choices[a] = c.toString();
                }
                spinnerSetting();
            }
        });

  spinnerSetting() contains the adapter configuration. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Please Do like this

```
fChoices = new ArrayList<>() ;

    rm.getAllCourses(new VolleyCallbackOp() {
        public void onSuccess4(List<Course> cl) {
            String [] choices = new String[cl.size()];
            for (int a = 0; a < cl.size(); a++) {
                Course c = cl.get(a);
                fChoices.add(c.toString());
                choices[a] = c.toString();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: yeah, i've tried before, but with the same " java.lang.NullPointerException". Maybe adapter is set before async volley task is completed?

Comment: can you just tell me where NullPointerException is occur?

Comment: at the arrayAdapter line..i believe adapter is setting before strings populate choices[]

Comment: Firstly you add the value in String Array after the create the ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Change this-:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices)
```

To-:

```
ArrayAdapter<Course> aa = new ArrayAdapter<Course>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices)
```

Comment: i got the same res :(

Comment: change ArrayList<Choices> fChoices = new ArrayList<>() ;

    rm.getAllCourses(new VolleyCallbackOp() {
        public void onSuccess4(List<Course> cl) {
            String [] choices = new String[cl.size()];
            for (int a = 0; a < cl.size(); a++) {
                Course c = cl.get(a);
                fChoices.add(c.toString());
                choices[a] = c.toString();
            }

        }
    });

Comment: Dnt specify it as string where your are using fchoices.

Comment: i use fChoice only as a support array, i can remove it. 

rm.getAllCourses(new VolleyCallbackOp() {
            public void onSuccess4(List<Course> cl) {
                String[] choices = new String[cl.size()];
                for (int a = 0; a < cl.size(); a++) {
                    Course c = cl.get(a);
                    choices[a] = c.toString();
                }
            }
        });

 this should be enough, but i've the same null reference.